# AngularJS two way binding math operations

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a currency converter, let's say, from Euro to USD using AngularJS' two way data binding such that when input Euro amount is changed, target USD amount, too, will change.

Here's what I have. It populates `usd_amount` field with the same value as `eur_amount` as I type:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<div ng-app>
  You pay (EUR):
  <input id="eur_amount" type="number" ng-model="eur_amount"><br>
  You get (USD):
  <input id="usd_amount" type="number" value="{{eur_amount}}"><br> <!-- {{eur_amount * 1.2 }}  -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

How can I multiply `{{eur_amount}}` variable with exchange rate, `$rate`, which is a PHP variable constructed earilier, to get `usd_amount`?

**EDIT**
Laravel's Blade templating engine and Angular use the same markup when displaying variables `{{variableName}}`. As I'm using Laravel, to access variable with `[[variableName]]`, I added scripts as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var toAmountCalculator = angular.module('toAmountCalculator', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    $scope.rate = '<?php echo $rate; ?>';
});
</script>
```

I can use `{{rate}}` (which is Blade's markup) to display `$rate` PHP variable. How can I display exchange rate with AngularJS' `[[rate]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the exchange rate in a scope variable and use * operator to multiple the same.

```
{{usd_amount * exchange_rate}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{eur_amount * 1.2 }}` in `value` attribute. Or you can assign a separate `ng-model` to the USD input, and apply a `ng-change` function to update the USD `ng-model`.